# How to modify an array using a C function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, ansi-c

I'm using ANSI C 89.
I would like to write a function that takes a two-dimensional array as a parameter and modifies it. Possibly without using structures or pointers.
My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define level 0
#define elements 1

void merge( int state[30][2] ){
  int index_state = 0;
  int array[30][2];
  int index_array = 0;
  memset (array, -1, sizeof(array));
  for ( index_state = 0; state[index_state][level] != -1; index_state++ ){
    if ( state[index_state][level] != 4 ){
      if ( index_state == 0 ){
        array[0][level] = state[index_state][level];
        array[0][elements] = state[index_state][elements];
      }
      else {
        if ( state[index_state][level] == array[index_array][level] ){
          array[index_array][elements] += state[index_state][elements];
        }
        else{
          index_array++;
          array[index_array][level] = state[index_state][level];
          array[index_array][elements] = state[index_state][elements];
       }      
     }
   }
 }
 state = array;
 int i = 0;

 printf("-----\nPrint values array inside function merge\n------\n");

 for ( i = 0; array[i][level] != -1 ; i++ ){
   printf("Level merge[%d]: %d, elements merge[%d]: %d.\n", i, array[i][level], i, array[i][elements]);
 }

 printf("-----\nPrint values state inside function merge\n------\n");

 for ( i = 0; state[i][level] != -1 ; i++ ){
   printf("Level merge[%d]: %d, elements merge[%d]: %d.\n", i, state[i][level], i, state[i][elements]);
 }
 }

int main(void) {
  int start_state[30][2] = {{0,4},{1,4},{2,32},{2,32},{4,64},{3,64},{2,64},{1,8},{2,8},{3,48},{4,64},{3,64},{2,4},{3,4},{4,12},{3,12},{2,16},{1,8},{-1,-1}};
  int i = 0;
  printf("-----\nPrint start_state.\n-----\n");
  for ( i = 0; start_state[i][level] != -1; i++){
    printf("start_state[%d][level] = %d, start_state[%d][elements] = %d.\n",i,start_state[i][level],i,start_state[i][elements]);
  }
  merge ( start_state );
  printf("-----\nPrint the merged start_state.\n-----\n");
  for ( i = 0; start_state[i][level] != -1; i++){
    printf("start_state[%d][level] = %d, start_state[%d][elements] = %d.\n",i,start_state[i][level],i,start_state[i][elements]);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The function takes the input correctly and does what I want it does. When I look at what the function prints everything's gone alright. When inside the function I print the internal array and the input modified I get the same result. But when it comes to the main function to print it looks like nothing happened. 
Here you are the output of the source code above.

```
-----
Print start_state.
-----
start_state[0][level] = 0, start_state[0][elements] = 4.
start_state[1][level] = 1, start_state[1][elements] = 4.
start_state[2][level] = 2, start_state[2][elements] = 32.
start_state[3][level] = 2, start_state[3][elements] = 32.
start_state[4][level] = 4, start_state[4][elements] = 64.
start_state[5][level] = 3, start_state[5][elements] = 64.
start_state[6][level] = 2, start_state[6][elements] = 64.
start_state[7][level] = 1, start_state[7][elements] = 8.
start_state[8][level] = 2, start_state[8][elements] = 8.
start_state[9][level] = 3, start_state[9][elements] = 48.
start_state[10][level] = 4, start_state[10][elements] = 64.
start_state[11][level] = 3, start_state[11][elements] = 64.
start_state[12][level] = 2, start_state[12][elements] = 4.
start_state[13][level] = 3, start_state[13][elements] = 4.
start_state[14][level] = 4, start_state[14][elements] = 12.
start_state[15][level] = 3, start_state[15][elements] = 12.
start_state[16][level] = 2, start_state[16][elements] = 16.
start_state[17][level] = 1, start_state[17][elements] = 8.
-----
Print values array inside function merge
------
Level merge[0]: 0, elements merge[0]: 4.
Level merge[1]: 1, elements merge[1]: 4.
Level merge[2]: 2, elements merge[2]: 64.
Level merge[3]: 3, elements merge[3]: 64.
Level merge[4]: 2, elements merge[4]: 64.
Level merge[5]: 1, elements merge[5]: 8.
Level merge[6]: 2, elements merge[6]: 8.
Level merge[7]: 3, elements merge[7]: 112.
Level merge[8]: 2, elements merge[8]: 4.
Level merge[9]: 3, elements merge[9]: 16.
Level merge[10]: 2, elements merge[10]: 16.
Level merge[11]: 1, elements merge[11]: 8.
-----
Print values state inside function merge
------
Level merge[0]: 0, elements merge[0]: 4.
Level merge[1]: 1, elements merge[1]: 4.
Level merge[2]: 2, elements merge[2]: 64.
Level merge[3]: 3, elements merge[3]: 64.
Level merge[4]: 2, elements merge[4]: 64.
Level merge[5]: 1, elements merge[5]: 8.
Level merge[6]: 2, elements merge[6]: 8.
Level merge[7]: 3, elements merge[7]: 112.
Level merge[8]: 2, elements merge[8]: 4.
Level merge[9]: 3, elements merge[9]: 16.
Level merge[10]: 2, elements merge[10]: 16.
Level merge[11]: 1, elements merge[11]: 8.
-----
Print the merged start_state.
-----
start_state[0][level] = 0, start_state[0][elements] = 4.
start_state[1][level] = 1, start_state[1][elements] = 4.
start_state[2][level] = 2, start_state[2][elements] = 32.
start_state[3][level] = 2, start_state[3][elements] = 32.
start_state[4][level] = 4, start_state[4][elements] = 64.
start_state[5][level] = 3, start_state[5][elements] = 64.
start_state[6][level] = 2, start_state[6][elements] = 64.
start_state[7][level] = 1, start_state[7][elements] = 8.
start_state[8][level] = 2, start_state[8][elements] = 8.
start_state[9][level] = 3, start_state[9][elements] = 48.
start_state[10][level] = 4, start_state[10][elements] = 64.
start_state[11][level] = 3, start_state[11][elements] = 64.
start_state[12][level] = 2, start_state[12][elements] = 4.
start_state[13][level] = 3, start_state[13][elements] = 4.
start_state[14][level] = 4, start_state[14][elements] = 12.
start_state[15][level] = 3, start_state[15][elements] = 12.
start_state[16][level] = 2, start_state[16][elements] = 16.
start_state[17][level] = 1, start_state[17][elements] = 8.
```

What should I edit to make the changes in the original array persistent? I had a look on the Internet and sometimes it seems this way it should work (isn't the second answer to this question [Passing modified array values back to main function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640330/passing-modified-array-values-back-to-main-function-in-c) similar to my case except for the two-dimensional array ?) and sometimes it looks like I must refer to the array using a pointer.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to/from a function in C. Only a pointer. And you hardly can do anything useful witha array either without using a pointer. Not even access an element. What do you want to accomplish? Provide a [mcve] (concentrate on the **Minimal**!).

Comment: Modifying variable of caller without pointer in C... Humm pretty sure that is impossible

Comment: You can't do it without pointers because with no pointers, your function will receive a COPY of the value. You can change the content, but once your function end, the copy gets destroyed, and the original will be still intact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `merge`, you are making changes to the local variable `array`. It makes sense you don't see the modifications to `array` in the calling function.

The line

```
 state = array;
```

does not copy the conents of `array` to `state`. It merely changes where `state` points to in the function.

Change `merge` to modify `state` itself and you will see the changes visible in the calling function.

Comment: Oh god, I thought it should have been something stupid but not this stupid. Many thanks.